# How to convert Recyclerview as PDF in android?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have created Recyclerview with list of items using card view.

I need to convert Recylerview items as PDF using Java in Android.

How can I do it?

Comment: Check this github project - https://github.com/UttamPanchasara/PDF-Generator

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PrintedPdfDocument](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/pdf/PrintedPdfDocument.html) available since API 19 to achieve this.

Sample implementation of this from the original doc is given as following:

```
// open a new document
PrintedPdfDocument document = new PrintedPdfDocument(context, printAttributes);
// start a page
Page page = document.startPage(0);
// draw something on the page
View content = getContentView();
content.draw(page.getCanvas());
// finish the page
document.finishPage(page);
// add more pages
// write the document content
document.writeTo(getOutputStream());
//close the document
document.close();
```